# tKinter How disable the Entry while checkbutton is unchecked and enable it while the checkbutton is checked

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

from tkinter import *
window=Tk()

nac = {}
ent = {}

for i in range(10):
    de = IntVar()
    nac[i]=IntVar()

```
na=Checkbutton(window, text='%s' % (i), borderwidth=1,variable = 
nac[i], onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,command=lambda e=ent, 
v=nac[i]:naccheck(e,v))
na.grid(row=i, column=0)
ent[i]=Entry(window,textvariable=de, state = DISABLED)
ent[i].grid(column=1,row=i,padx=20)
```

window.mainloop()

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always re-read your question after posting it. Here you should especially looking for code formatting. Also you should not only post your code but also explain your problem in detail. In addition, titles should not contain tags. And when tagging your question, you should read the tag description. For your python-3.7 tag it says that it should only be used when your question is version specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

def entry():
    ent[i].configure(state = NORMAL)

window=Tk()

nac = {}
ent = {}

for i in range(10):
    de = IntVar()
    nac[i]=IntVar()

na=Checkbutton(window, text='%s' % (i), borderwidth=1,variable = nac[i],
               onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,command=entry)
na.grid(row=i, column=0)
ent[i]=Entry(window,textvariable=de, state = DISABLED)
ent[i].grid(column=1,row=i,padx=20)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of posting just code